# Is there a way to render LaTEX/MathJax for Slack Chatting client (web or app)?

Tags: plugins, latex, chat, rendering, api

I have a workgroup that uses the Slack chatting app/website/destop version to communicate, and the desire to send usable mathematical expressions across to friends is something we'd like to do there. While it doesnt seem like there is any official implementation of LaTeX or a plugin for it there are many ways for DIY integration: [image]

I wanted to know how to get LaTeX rendering working on Slack, be it through integrations and/or customization of Slack and/or through web hooking. The only thing I'd prefer **not** to do is hook out to another website, make the render into **a picture**, and then hook it back into Slack.

Comment: Please note: Fredrik Savje's accepted answer links to [his GitHub repo](https://github.com/fsavje/math-with-slack) for a script that no-longer works since Slack v.4.  However, Savje's repo points to [thisiscam's repo](https://github.com/thisiscam/math-with-slack) which has an updated working version of the script.  (Unfortunately, the edit queue for Savje's answer here on StackExchange is full, so I can't edit it.) After re-installing Slack per [this issue](https://github.com/thisiscam/math-with-slack/issues/8), the new script worked for me on MacOS.

Answer (score 40):

I made a small [script](https://github.com/fsavje/math-with-slack) that installs MathJax in Slack's desktop client (basically the same solution as [goatandsheep's](https://superuser.com/a/988121/701201), but with some Electron hacking). No server needed, supports both inline and display math, and equations can be edited.

https://github.com/fsavje/math-with-slack

[image: Math in Slack]

Comment: This worked immediately.

Comment: This would be pretty awesome, but unfortunately doesn't work for me on Mac Sierra. :( Any pointers would be great.

Comment: @space_cadet I'm sorry to hear that it does work for you. Please file a bug report on github and describe your problem as detailed as possible: https://github.com/fsavje/math-with-slack/issues

Comment: Works fine in Mac Mojave (Jan 2019). Thanks a million!

Comment: @FredrikSavje, Hi, Is there a way that I can install the script on the workspace?

Comment: Unfortunately Slack 4.0.0 has killed the script. Hoping for a fix.

Comment: [Savje's GitHub repo](https://github.com/fsavje/math-with-slack) now links to a repo with [an updated version of the script from thisiscam](https://github.com/thisiscam/math-with-slack).  It worked for me on MacOS.  Note, [per this issue](https://github.com/thisiscam/math-with-slack/issues/8), that you may need to un-install Slack and do a fresh re-install before the script works.

Answer (score 13):

[I've written a Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey script](https://gist.github.com/goatandsheep/c8bf7b4ae448e76208a0) that you can install as an extension that will render it.

Edit: It's had trouble rendering on streams, since it compiles the content at page load. If someone knows how to do that, that would be awesome.

Edit: [MathJax CDN has shut down](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking over that now. Any chance you could add a little more clarification text to the installer it for people who still dont know know Slack inside and out.

Comment: 1. Download [Tampermonkey for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) or [Greasemonkey for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
2. Add new userscript.
3. Paste the contents of the file into it.

Comment: Have others had success using the Greasemonkey script? For me, it appears to be installed but does not render equations in my Slack forum.

Comment: MathJax has not shut down. The only think that's shut down is one of their CDN.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino thank you for the correction. They have not shut down, but their CDN has. They are using CloudFlare CDN now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slack plugin on github, check it out https://github.com/colbygk/mathslax

Also there are Latex plugins from community mentioned by Slack itself https://api.slack.com/community

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

We just built an app to embed LaTeX into Slack https://slacklatex.com. But to work on web/mobile/desktop without installing custom software on every system, it has to render as images. Disclosure: I’m one of the authors.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an app for this on the slack and Rocket.Chat app store.

https://apps.rocketbooster.net/math

Comment: It does not look like it parses Latex.

Comment: It doesn't, its a math solver bot

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "math" in the Slack app directory, there is an app called "latexbot" that renders latex in Slack. We use it at work and it seems to work fine.
Edit: Here's the direct link to the slack app: https://nobitasoft.com/latexbot/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you could include a direct link to the app his answer would be better.